# How to move docker image to a different folder

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I pushed a Docker image to a remote repository, eg:

```
docker-dev-artifactory.XXX.XX/kafka:latest
```

How do I move it to

```
docker-dev-artifactory.XXX.XX/tomas/kafka:latest
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
docker tag docker-dev-artifactory.XXX.XX/kafka:latest docker-dev-artifactory.XXX.XX/tomas/kafka:latest

docker push docker-dev-artifactory.XXX.XX/tomas/kafka:latest
```